# Java array fills, and values print. But, memory always prints after

Tags: java, arrays, memory, java.util.scanner

My project its to take in and read a file then load its contents into an array, the have a user alter it and find things from it. My problem though is when I go to search the array it always prints out the contents, along with something that is stored in the memory. I can't figure out how to stop it because I can't figure out what that something is. This is what it prints though Directory1@27391d.

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Directory1{


   private int size=0;
   private String[] dval;//Sting Array


   public Directory1(String directoryFileName){

    int size=0;//counter for the array Size
    int ct=0;//counter
    dval = new String[size];//New String array

    File file= new File(directoryFileName);

   try{
      Scanner insert = new Scanner(file);
      Scanner populate= new Scanner(file);//Scans File

      //Counts the amount of lines to get array size
      while(populate.hasNextLine()){
         String i= populate.nextLine();
         size++;
         }
         dval= new String[size];



      //Inserts values into the array
      for(int i=0;i<dval.length;i++){
         String j= insert.nextLine();
         dval[ct]= j;
         System.out.println(dval[ct]);
         ct++;


      }
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }//End Constructor
```

}
When I Initialize it using this it always prints out the names in the directory but also prints out 
something in the memory.

```
public class Directory{ 
   public static void main(String[] args){

   Directory1 direct= new Directory1("directory.txt");
   System.out.println(direct);

}
}
```

Comment: For one, arrays are not resizable in Java; then, why don't you just use `Files.readAllLines()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to print directly from the constructor.  But the reason that `Directory1@27391d` is being printed is that you are attempting to print the object itself.  You haven't overridden `toString()`, so what you see is the `String` returned from [the inherited `toString()` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Create a `toString()` method in `Directory1` to override `Object`'s `toString()` method and create a `String` from what you were trying to print in your `println` statements and return it in that method.